# PHP Problem : filesize() return 0 with file containing few data?

Tags: java, php

I use PHP to call a Java command then forward its result into a file called result.txt. For ex, the file contains this:
"Result is : 5.0"
but the function filesize() returns 0 and when I check by 'ls -l' command it's also 0. Because I decide to print the result to the screen when file size != 0 so nothing is printed. How can I get the size in bit ? or another solution available?

Comment: Instead of using `filesize()` you could just open the file and use `strlen()` to see if there are one or more characters inside the file.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the [docs](http://th.php.net/filesize), when you call `filesize`, PHP caches this result in the stat cache.

Have you tried clearing the stat cache?

```
clearstatcache();
```

If it does not work, possible workaround is to open the file, seek to its end, and then use `ftell`.

```
$fp = fopen($filename, "rb");
fseek($fp, 0, SEEK_END);
$size = ftell($fp);
fclose($fp);
```

If you are actually planning to display the output to the user, you can instead read the entire file and then `strlen`.

```
$data = file_get_contents($filename);
$size = strlen($data);
```

Comment: at the end I unlink the result file so I think its cache is cleared too. I prefer the file_get_contents() func that you suggest. many thanks

Comment: `clearstatcache()` did it for me. For completeness, one may also invalidate a specific file's stat cache, as opposed to the entire stat cache, by calling `clearstatcache(true, $filename);`

Answer (score 0):

Which function do you use ? 
Because [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) can directly assign result to a variable, so maybe there's no need to save output to a file, if you just want to load it in PHP.

Comment: yes.I use exec(). I tried as you suggested: exec("java st $str",$result) with $str is arguments and result is array() and then var_dump it  but it print out nothing

Comment: @silentbang, perhaps that is your initial problem. If the $result has no length, why would putting it into a file and then reading the file be any different?

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> I use PHP to call a Java command then
>   forward its result into a file called
>   result.txt.

Who does the result writing?

1.The JAVA programm?

2.Do you catch the output in PHP and write it to the file.

3.Do you just redirect the output from command line?

If 1 and 3 you might have a delay between when the result is written in the file so, practically, when you read the file in PHP, if you don't wait for the execution to finish, you read it befor it even was written with the result.

Comment: I redirect result by php by ' > ' symbol through exec() function.after hours, its size still stays the same (0)

Comment: you should try catching the output in PHP, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php on how to do that