# filesize() return 0 ?

Tags: php, filesize

im trying to insert an array values into the file using foreach.. and if the file size became up to 1MB (1000000byte). the script create a new file and put the value inside...

this is the code what i used :

```php
foreach($array as $code){  

if(filesize($file_name) < '1000000'){
    $update_file = file_get_contents($file_name);
    file_put_contents($file_name,$update_file.$code);
}else{
    $open = fopen($file_name.rand('99999'),'w');
    file_put_contents($file_name,$code);

    }
echo filesize($file_name);
}
```

now the problem is the function "filesize()" is always returning 0,, but if i remove the code above it and put `echo filesize($file_name);` only in the page .. it return the right value (size of file), the script also make only 1 file even it became more than 1MB because the filesize is 0 as filesize() function return !.

i checked this question [PHP Problem : filesize() return 0 with file containing few data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167313/php-problem-filesize-return-0-with-file-containing-few-data)
but it still not working even i follow the answer #1

i wish that you understand my problem.. and im sorry for my english.

Comment: try to close and reopen file,then write in it.I think it's because of buffer.

Comment: @Moein7tl i tried, but didn't work

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone `$file_name` is in the header of the page, it contains a string value and its `file.txt`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

function filesize is cached internally
you need to explicitly use `clearstatcache` after each write

beside this, the usage of file_put_contents does not seem to be correct

please refer to [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) for more information