# file size returns every time 0 and file contents not displayed, even if file exists with data

Tags: php, filesystems

Good evening everybody!

I have a problem with my filesystem. When I try to open an existing file the file size is every time 0 and when I try to read the data (on different ways) it only returns "". I did not found any solution on the web so I ask here.

Here my code:

```
function getOldDate($id) {
    $file = fopen($id.".txt", "r+");
    if ($file) {
        $fileURL = $id.'.txt';
        echo "fread:".fread($file,filesize($fileURL));
        echo "ID:".$fileURL;
        echo "file_get_contents:".file_get_contents($fileURL)."      ;";
        echo "Lines:".fgets($file)."        ;";
        print_r($id.":".file_get_contents($fileURL));
        return date("d.m.Y, h:i", strtotime(file_get_contents($fileURL)));
    }
    fclose($file);
}
```

I write the data with following code:

```
function saveNewDate($id, $newdate) {
    $file = fopen($id.".txt", "w");
    if ($file) {
        fclose($file);
        unlink($id.".txt");
    }
    $fileN = fopen($id.".txt", "w");
    fwrite($fileN, $newdate);
    fclose($fileN);         
}
```

The returned website looks like this:

```
Warning: fread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0 in /storage/ssd2/016/3537016/public_html/run.php on line 83
fread:ID:VPuem.txtfile_get_contents: ;Lines: ;VPuem:Savedate:01.01.1970, 01:00 ModDate:10.11.2017, 09:43 

Warning: fread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0 in /storage/ssd2/016/3537016/public_html/run.php on line 83
fread:ID:K11_1.txtfile_get_contents: ;Lines: ;K11_1:Savedate:01.01.1970, 01:00 ModDate:20.10.2017, 05:05 

Warning: fread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0 in /storage/ssd2/016/3537016/public_html/run.php on line 83
fread:ID:K12_1.txtfile_get_contents: ;Lines: ;K12_1:Savedate:01.01.1970, 01:00 ModDate:20.09.2017, 06:19
```

The content of the VPuem.txt file:

> 20.10.2017, 05:05

The contents of the other files are the same, only the date (numbers) is different.

Oh, and the files are in the same directory like the PHP file.

Hopefully someone can help. I am sitting on this for 4 hours now...

**Edit:
I found out, that the file is read, after editing it with the saveNewDate() method. The question now is: Why?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. On the top of the code there was a code snippet with testing code from earlier this day (4 am) and I had forgotten to delete it this morning. Now the codes works totally fine.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5167585/6859959) is what you're looking for. Since your file contains very little data, it's harder to get an accurate reading. The answer to the linked question explains a few workarounds for this.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work either. Data is still "" and Size is 0...